# How can you Import Forge Mods into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Specifically I'm trying to edit this mod: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/naruto-anime-mod-plus/files/3050483

I'm not just trying to edit the config, I want to add custom stuff as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it easily because the mods is NOT open-source. In fact, it's *All right reserved*, so you are not allowed to do it. So do **at your own risk**.

#### 1) Get the source code

You can ask to the original dev, but it's sure it will decline your question.

Else, you have to [decompile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JD_Decompiler) the jar thanks to utilities like [javadecompilers.com](http://www.javadecompilers.com/).

#### 2) Create a new Java Project in eclipse

Create a blank java project

#### 3) Copy/paste the code in your eclipse project

*The code obtain thanks to decompilation

#### 4) Before using it, you should fix all decompilation issue.

Finally, I think it's a better idea to create a new one, specially because it will be faster to upgrade it in 1.17 or make more edition.

Comment: Ok thank you that’s what I’ve been doing so thanks for the reassurance